# Download channel fields to csv file?

Tags: csv

We are using Andrew Weaver's DataGrab to upload about 50 fields via a spreadsheet - all works fine (great plugin btw) - what we need though is to somehow do the reverse process: basically take the submitted channel entries, but only ones assigned to the logged in author and output them as a csv?

Andrew has a plugin ‘Export’ but it seems rudimentary and the channel I need to download info on has 50 fields, plus some categories and must be in a category the logged in author is assigned to. Not sure that would do it.

Anyone have ideas or done something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Kind of depends on your budget, but in a pinch, Mithra62's "[export it](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/export-it)" add-on would definitely allow you to handle that.

Comment: Yeah, looks like. The problem is though the client is a non-profit and out of budget. They definitely can't stretch.